# Question on the proof that jump times of a Poisson process are totally inaccessible

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, poisson-process

I am reading the proof that the jump times of a Poisson process are totally inaccessible from the following post : https://almostsuremath.com/2010/06/24/poisson-processes/#scn_pp_def1

From definition 9 in https://almostsuremath.com/2009/11/30/predictable-stopping-times/#scn_pst_def1

a stopping time $\tau$ is totally inaccessible if $P(\sigma=\tau<\infty)=0$ for all predictable stopping times $\sigma$.

In the proof below, the author shows that, using the compensated process $M_t=X_t - \lambda t$ being a martingale, that the jump times of a Poisson process $X$ are totally inaccessible, by showing that $P(\Delta X_\tau \neq 0)=0$ for each predictable stopping time $\tau$.

My questions are:

1. In the proof, how are we able to replace $\tau$ by $\tau \wedge t$? How does this not hurt generality here?
2. In the final equalities, how are we able to take the limit outside of the expectation in computing $E[M_\tau - M_{\tau_n}]$?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1: Suppose that $\tau \wedge t$ is totally inaccessible for all $t>0$ and let $\sigma$ be a predictable stopping time.  By the monotone convergence theorem for sets, $P(\sigma = \tau < \infty) = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} P(\sigma = \tau \wedge t < \infty)$.  But for all $t > 0$ we have $\tau \wedge t$ is totally inaccessible, so $P(\sigma = \tau \wedge t < \infty) = 0$, and hence $P(\sigma = \tau < \infty) = 0$ as well.

For 2: This follows from the fact that $M_{\tau_n} = \mathbb{E}[M_\tau | \mathcal F_{\tau_n}]$ and $\{\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal B]: \mathcal B \text{ is a sub-$\sigma$ algebra}\}$ is a uniformly integrable class of random variables for any integrable $X$.

Comment: I assume you mean $t\to \infty$ in the limit?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  It's fixed now.